# query results inconsistent with results in database

Tags: sql, jpa

I am trying to retrieve a list of results from the database right after an update operation, however, the results returned are the still the old results(prior to the update) even though the changes by the update have been commited to the database(verified).
For better understanding I am doing an update on the data with:
   `query=em.createNamedQuery("user.addNewUser").executeUpdate();`
and following it up with

`em.clear();
em.createNamedQuery("user.findAllActiveUsers").getResultList();`

However, the results returned in the applications, are still the pre-udpate results, even though the database itself reflects the updated values.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you clear the persistence context. Did you try without that line?

Comment: Why are you using a query to create a new record? Post all relevant code.

Comment: Most likely your issue is related to the fact the the JPA spec states that "The persistence context is not synchronized with the result of the bulk update or delete" and from which we can deduce that the same might apply for adding a new record via an insert query as opposed to calling em.persist(...).

Comment: the synchronization executed just when the transaction closed or a flush called on it manually

Comment: im not sure what you mean, by not using persistent context. how else do i execute an update query?